# Why does __new__ method need passing cls argument when called its parent's __new__ across super method?

Tags: python, super

I know when we called parent's method across super method we could ignore the "self" argument in a bound method just as below:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__() # We needn't pass in the "self" argument
        # ...
```

But something been different in `__new__` method:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Bar, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) # Why need a "cls" argument?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__new__` is not an instance method; it is a static method that is passed the class object (making it not quite a class method either).

From the [`__new__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument.

As such, even when using `super()` to look up the next `__new__` method in the MRO, you still need to pass in `cls` explicitly.

Special methods with double-underscores are normally looked up on the *type*, so on the metaclass of the class (which is `type()` by default). That wouldn't work for `__new__` because you declared it directly on the class itself. As such no [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) can be applied *either* (which is what normally turns a function into a bound method, for class and instance methods). Thus the `__new__` hook had to be special-cased and is never bound.

Comment: Thank you, i know it, before i can use it, don't reason.